# Does Tailwind CSS remove unused custom CSS classes in production?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have read [Tailwind CSS: Optimizing for Production](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production). So far what I have understood that

> **Tailwind CSS removes unused CSS from your production builds for maximum performance**

My question is what about the external CSS files? Are those custom CSS classes will be removed on production?

Comment: Tailwind will go through your template file and check the classes/ids and only keep those classes/ids in css file. If you have an external css file tailwind never have access to that file to change/remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TW does not access your external CSS files.  From the docs you linked to:

> Removing all unused styles
> By default, Tailwind will only remove unused classes that it generates itself, or has been explicitly wrapped in a @layer directive. It will not remove unused styles from third-party CSS you pull in to your project, like a datepicker library you pull in for example.